# Why is the remote Sensu Client not visible in Uchiwa?

Tags: rabbitmq, sensu, uchiwa

I have setup sensu on a Centos 6.5 box and installed/configured the client on the sensu box so it monitors itself like so

**/etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json**

```
{
  "client": {
    "name": "sensu",
    "address": "10.100.1.200",
    "subscriptions": [
      "ALL"
    ]
  }
}
```

This works fine and it shows up in Uchiwa, but now I have another host I want to register with Sensu/Uchiwa and it does not show up in clients under Uchiwa/Sensu

Here's the configuration on the client "coffee"

**/etc/sensu/conf.d/rabbitmq.json**

```
{
 "rabbitmq":{
  "host": "10.100.1.200",
  "port": "5672",
  "vhost": "/sensu",
  "user": "user",
  "pass": "pass"
 }
}
```

**/etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json**

```
{
  "client": {
    "name": "coffee",
    "address": "10.100.1.19",
    "subscriptions": [
      "ALL"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I tail the /var/log/sensu/sensu-client.log on coffee I see the following:

```
{"timestamp":"2015-07-13T07:15:52.856009-0500","level":"warn","message":"loading config file","file":"/etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json"}
{"timestamp":"2015-07-13T07:15:52.856157-0500","level":"warn","message":"config file applied changes","file":"/etc/sensu/conf.d/client.json","changes":{"client":{"subscriptions":[["ALL","ALL"],["ALL"]]}}}
{"timestamp":"2015-07-13T07:15:52.856235-0500","level":"warn","message":"loading config file","file":"/etc/sensu/conf.d/rabbitmq.json"}
{"timestamp":"2015-07-13T07:15:52.856330-0500","level":"warn","message":"config file applied changes","file":"/etc/sensu/conf.d/rabbitmq.json","changes":{"rabbitmq":{"port":[5672,"5672"],"pass":"REDACTED"}}}
{"timestamp":"2015-07-13T07:15:52.859696-0500","level":"warn","message":"loading extension files from directory","directory":"/etc/sensu/extensions"}
{"timestamp":"2015-07-13T07:15:53.051176-0500","level":"warn","message":"reconnecting to transport"}
```

It looks like it's talking to RabbitMQ but for some reason the client does not appear in Uchiwa.  How can I dive into this further and figure out what's going on and get the coffee server to register?

Comment: So I was getting a Plain login refused error in the rabbitmq logs.  I changed the password to something like pAssW0Rd (not my actual password fyi) and rabbitmq allowed the sensu client to connect.  But now it's still not showing in my Uchiwa dashboard.

Comment: Here's the log showing the connection =INFO REPORT==== 13-Jul-2015::12:22:22 ===
accepting AMQP connection <0.435.0> (10.100.1.19:43998 -> 10.100.1.200:5672)

Comment: You should try to verify the logs for sensu-server (`/var/log/sensu/sensu-server.log`) and sensu-api (`/var/log/sensu/sensu-api.log`). Since the Uchiwa dashboard uses the sensu-api to retrieve information about your clients, you could start by making sure they appear in the API.

Comment: They do show up in the sensu-api.log actually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was caused by a significant time difference between the `sensu-client` and `sensu-server`.

```
user@sensu-server:~# date
Mon Aug 15 06:17:37 UTC 2016
```

vs.

```
user@sensu-client:~$ date
ma aug 15 08:17:37 CEST 2016
```

**Solution**

The issue was solved by synchronizing the clocks using `timedatectl`:

```
user@sensu-server:~# sudo timedatectl list-timezones
Africa/Abidjan
Africa/Accra
Africa/Addis_Ababa
Africa/Algiers
...
```

and changing the timezone by issuing:

```
user@sensu-server:~# sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Amsterdam
```

synchronized the time on the server with the client:

```
user@sensu-server:~# date
Mon Aug 15 08:25:14 UTC 2016
```

After restarting the `sensu-services` and `rabbitmq` the client was found in the `sensu-api` and registered in Uchiwa.

Comment: I'm shocked this is a thing, but thanks for your answer.  Spent hours on this.  `UTC` for everything I guess...